# Export to Word from datalist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview, datalist

I have made a gridview which will display a datalist to be able to edit and export to word

i datalist contain textbox. i am able to export to word but the layout of it contain textboxes and the text is unable to see and needs to scroll as it is embedded in the text box

```
     protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
       Response.Clear(); 
       Response.Buffer = true; 
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename-WordDoc.doc"); 
       Response.Charset = ""; 
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
       StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
       HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTxtWriter(sw); 
       DataList1.DataBind(); 
       DataList1.RenderControl(hw);
       Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString()); 
       Response.Flush(); 
       Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Or do you mean you are seeing the textbox also in the word document?

Comment: @KiranHegde I'm seeing the textbox inside the word document but i only want the text

Comment: Can you please show the data list html code?